# Compute dependent probability

Tags: probability

I have
$X = \pmatrix{-2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
.05 & .2 & .3 & .4 & .05} $, $$F(X) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & X \le -2 \\ 
.05 & -2 \le X < -1 \\ 
.25 & -1 \le X < 0 \\ 
.55 & 0 \le X < 1 \\ 
.95 & 1 \le X < 2 \\ 
1 & 2 \le X
\end{cases}
$$

I must compute:
$$
P(X > -2.1\ |\ X < 1.3) \\ 
$$

I know Bayes formula that says:
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) \times P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

I computed:
$P(A) = P(X > -2.1) = 1 - F(-2.1) = 1$ and $P(B) = P(X<1.3) = F(1.3) = \frac{95}{100}$ but I don't know how to compute $P(B|A)$

Comment: You don't need _Bayes'_ formula at all, just the _definition_ of conditional probability $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

Comment: Is this correct then?
$$P(X > -2.1 \cap X < 1.3) = P(-2.1 < X < 1.3)$$

Comment: You need to find $P(A\cap B) = P\{-2.1 < X < 1.3\}$. Can you express this in terms of the distribution function $F(\cdot)$ and get the answer from what you know of the values of $F(\cdot)$?

Comment: Well then 
$$P(-2.1 < X < 1.3) = F(1.3) - F(-2.1) = \frac{95}{100}$$

Right?

Comment: Yes, that is the value of $P(A\cap B)$. Don't forget to divide by $P(B) = \frac{95}{100}$ to get $P(A\mid B) = 1$ as pointed out in gt6989b's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one, no complex formula seems necessary. Note all values for $X$ are in $[-2,2]$, so $X$ is always at least $-2.1$. Thus, (since $\mathbb{P}[X<1.3] \neq 0$), your probability is $\mathbb{P}[X>-2.1|X<1.3]=1$.